# Is chrome.storage.sync data protected by the Chrome sync passphrase?

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, google-chrome-extension

The documentation says that confidential information should not be stored:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

> Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted.

But it seems users do have the option of choosing their own passphrase to encrypt their Chrome sync data:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035

So which one is it? Is Chrome extension data also protected by the sync passphrase?

Also, I don't get this bit:

> When you sign in to Chrome and enable sync, Chrome keeps your information secure by using your Google Account credentials to encrypt your synced passwords. Alternatively, you can choose to encrypt all of your synced data with a sync passphrase. This sync passphrase is stored on your computer and isn't sent to Google.

Why exactly is the passphrase *stored* on the computer? It doesn't make it any more secure.

Answer (score 5):

The `chrome.storage` area is not encrypted anyhow while on your machine. That's why the first warning is there, and it's valid.

When transmitted to Google servers, you can opt to secure it with an additional layer of encryption - but only while it's on Google's servers. It's a protection against trying to get your data (to an new device, or from a hypothetical attack on Google servers).

It's stored on the computer, so that Google never sees it and can't decrypt data on its servers. But you need to passphrase to work with this data, and Chrome does not ask for it every time it syncs data (which very often) - it's stored locally.

Think of it like a box with a lock. Instead of giving Google a plain-text document, you give Google a box with said document and keep the key to yourself. Meanwhile, while working on that document, you keep your local copy outside the box, and you keep your key handy in case the box is sent by Google to you.